# gwt app download multiple images from other server

Tags: image, gwt

I have a gwt app that need to display images thats hosted by other server, i used the Image(url) to create those icon, but it's unbearably slow, (need to display up to 50 images on one page), is there any way i can speed up? i looked a bit of image bundle but seems it only works for the images hosted on my own server.

here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 50; i++) {
  item = items.get(i);
  icon = new Image(ROOT_URL + item.getIconURI());

  ....
}
```

Comment: If images are always different, there is no other way - you have to load them one by one. If images are always the same, why can't you host them on your server?

Comment: images are always different

Answer (score 0):

1) If there is not security concern ( just images right ) ensure that you are not requesting over **https**.

2) Use Chrome Dev Tools - Network Profiler to monitor the page load and http requests. Tune your application using the profiler suggestions.

3) Try precaching the images ( i.e ) fetch them before the user navigates to the page in the background.

4) You can also try requesting the image host to send compressed images if they are not compressed already.

The above suggestion have very little to do with GWT.